# Email templates: 2 responsive divs with empty space between them

Tags: html, css, templates, html-email

i have a problem with 2 divs that have to show right next to each other with space between them. It has to be responsive ofc and the max-width can only be 600px while the min-width has to be 280px. 
It actually works as intended when i open the html in the browser, but when i send it as a mail, the two divs are right next to each other, with the space being above the second div instead of between them. Also they are fixated to the left for some reason.
How it looks in the browser (and how it should look):
[image]

How it looks after being sent per mail:
[image]

So i dont really know why it doesnt work as intended..
Also sorry for all that code, but if you test it in a browser u can see, that it works perfectly fine , which it doesnt when used as a mail template..

```html
<div style="background: url('http://www.iuno-projekt.de/media/com_acymailing/templates/newsletter/img/hintergrund.png'); max-width: 700px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <div class="layout two-col" style="Margin: 0 auto;max-width: 600px;min-width: 280px; width: calc(28000% - 167400px);overflow-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-word;">
    <div class="layout__inner" style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;">
      <div class="column" style="background: #ffffff; Float: left;max-width: 280px;min-width: 280px; width: 280px;text-align: left;color: #8e959c;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;font-family: sans-serif; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div style="">
          <div style="font-size: 12px;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;line-height: 19px;Margin-bottom: 20px;" align="center">
            <img style="border: 0;display: block;height: auto;width: 100%;max-width: 450px;" alt="some img" width="260">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px; background: #ffffff;">
          <div style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-text-raise: 4px;">
            <h3 style="Margin-top: 0;Margin-bottom: 12px;color: #3b4554; font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 800; letter-spacing: 0.015em; line-height: 1.15em; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 0 20px;"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="background: #ffffff; Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;">
          <div style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-text-raise: 4px;">
            <p style="Margin-top: 0;Margin-bottom: 20px;">..........</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;">
          <div class="btn btn--depth btn--medium" style="Margin-bottom: 20px;text-align: center;">
            <a href="http://www.iuno-projekt.de/aktuelles.html?view=article&amp;id=194"><img src="http://www.iuno-projekt.de/media/com_acymailing/templates/newsletter/img/right-arrow-grn.png" alt="icon" />MORE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;">
          <div style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 15px;font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="Float: left; max-width: 40px; width: 40px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" align="center">
        <div style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 15px;font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background: #ffffff; Float: left;max-width: 280px;min-width: 280px; width: 280px;text-align: left;color: #8e959c;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;font-family: sans-serif; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

        <div style="">
          <div style="font-size: 12px;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;line-height: 19px;Margin-bottom: 20px;" align="center">
            <img style="border: 0;display: block;height: auto;width: 100%;max-width: 450px;" alt="some img" width="260">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div style="Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px; background: #ffffff;">
          <div style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-text-raise: 4px;">
            <h3 style="Margin-top: 0;Margin-bottom: 12px;color: #3b4554; font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 800; letter-spacing: 0.015em; line-height: 1.15em; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 0 20px;"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div style="background: #ffffff; Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;">
          <div style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-text-raise: 4px;">
            <p style="Margin-top: 0;Margin-bottom: 20px;">.........</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div style="Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;">
          <div class="btn btn--depth btn--medium" style="Margin-bottom: 20px;text-align: center;">
            <a href="http://www.iuno-projekt.de/aktuelles.html?view=article&amp;id=194"><img src="http://www.iuno-projekt.de/media/com_acymailing/templates/newsletter/img/right-arrow-grn.png" alt="icon" />MORE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;">
          <div style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 15px;font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **@N. Ivanov** said :

> Email templates do not work the same way that would a browser work. You will be best off generating a proper HTML template using the `table` tag rather than divs.

So for those of you who must use tables in your **HTML emails**
, I have some information about how they perform across the board. I ran some tests and discovered that, while I couldn’t find a perfect solution, I did manage to collect some useful tips to make your tables behave for the most part.

---

### Table Math, Meet Box-Model Math

---

So it turns out that when one places table widths, td widths, td padding and `CSS padding` into a blender, the results are quite chaotic. Inconsistent, to the say the least. Take, for example, the following table:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" height="450" cellpadding="0" border="1px" width="400">

<tr height="100%">

<td width="100" border="1px" height="100%"></td>

<td width="300" border="1px" height="100%"></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Just as intended, the resulting width of this table is  `400 pixels` and the width of the columns are `100 and 300 pixels`:

[image]

But when some `padding` is added—via either `CSS` or `HTML—the widths` of `the columns` are compromised:

[image]

However, when table width is kissed good bye, the results are not unlike a **CSS box model**. If `padding` is added to the original example and the table `width`is removed, the code looks like this:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" height="450" cellpadding="10" border="1">

<tr>

<td width="80" height="100%" border="1"></td>

<td width="280" height="100%" border="1"></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

And, as intended, the resulting `widths` are correct for both the `table` and the `columns`:

[image]

But note how the td widths were reduced to accommodate the new padding. This is just like the **CSS box model** in which `100 pixels` wide + `10 pixels padding` = `120 pixels` total.

**

### Nested Tables

**

If a table is nested inside another, the aforementioned rules apply with the exception of a couple important variances:

- Yahoo Mail (new), Gmail, Outlook 2007 and Eudora apply extra width to account for borders. But only when they are nested, as the parent table behaves appropriately.
- Applying widths to td tags that also have CSS or HTML padding creates confusion across the board. Nearly every client renders the widths in its own unique fashion.
- Even without any borders there are variances in width by 2–4 pixels for a nested table with two columns. My tests were inconclusive as to the rhyme and reason behind this unnatural phenomenon. Just know that pixel perfect isn’t an option (unless there is some hidden secret behind this).

[source->](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2007/07/tables-in-html-emails-nesting/)

Comment: @whitesilly using the tips in my answer you can add an empty td between the td with the your content , and that would be your empty space, and also you can use percentage in width, if you give the main table an fixed width, for the responsive view, and would you mark it as answered for the community.

Comment: Yeah sure, sorry. And thanks again. Gonna try it out.

Comment: Your answer gives rhe basics of email which is good but personally I would have gone with ghost tables and columns. It would have kept the structure as in the OP and more can be added with CSS.

Comment: yes i agree , ghost table would be a great solution for alignment Problems in Outlook

Answer (score 1):

Email templates do not work the same way that would a browser work. You will be best off generating a proper HTML template using the `<table>` tag rather than divs. Further you should only use inline `CSS` and not use any classes for example `bootstrap` ones. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! Ive used a table before and somehow it was even worse, thats why i used divs. Guess i gonna try table again.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ In email client  css are supported in a very different way